# append a match in a string using regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex, append

I would like to use regular expressions to search a string, match a word, and manipulate the final outcome.  The string is a title of the book, for example, "The Great Gatsby", "A Wonderful Life", or "An Epidemic".  The goal is to take the words, "the", "a", and "an" and append them at the end of the title with a comma so they are displayed as such: "Great Gatsby, The", "Wonderful Life, A", and "Epidemic, An".  Is there a method using regular expressions that can do this?

Comment: Yes there is; use `Regex.Replace()`.

Comment: You should be careful with such an approach. You don't want to turn "To kill a mockingbird" into "To kill mockingbird, A". You need to look at the first word.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for most any title:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(title, @"^(The|A|An)\b.+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    title = Regex.Replace(title, @"^((The|A|An)\s)?(.*)$", "$3, $1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input,"^(\\w+\\s*)(.+)$","$2, $1");
```